# Integral Function Paradox

Tags: calculus, functions

I have found a result that truly puzzles me in a calculation. 
Assume a function $f(x)$. Then there should be some function $I(x)$ such that

$I(f(x)) = \int(f(x)) dx$
Taking the derivative with respect to x would yield:
$I'(f(x)) f'(x) = f(x)$
But this does not make sense does it? Because in this respect
$f'(x) = 0" $ would imply $f(x) = 0"$, which it does not of course. So where is my mistake?

Comment: You recieved two answers to your question. Is any of then what you were looking for? If so, the standard practice on this site is to *accept* the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assume a function f(x). Then there should be some function I(x) such that
>   $$I(f(x)) = \int(f(x)) dx.$$

**False**.

There are two problems with what you wrote:

1. $\int f(x) dx$ is *not* a function, it is a *family* of functions. Therefore, $I$ must map to the set of families of functions, not to the set $\mathbb R$.
2. Take for example $f(x)=1$, which means $\int f(x)dx = x+C$. Even if we set $C$ to $0$, the problem is that **there exists no such function $I$** such that $I(f(x))=x$, because $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, which means $I(f(x))$ is **constant** for all $x$. So, you should say $(I(f))(x)$, not $I(f(x))$ (mind the parentheses!)

So, the only way to make your statement work is for $I$ to be a mapping from the set of functions to the set of families of functions, and then $I'$ is not really defined.

Comment: @Arthur I edited my answer to explain both problems (i.e. the one where the function $I$ might not exist, for example if $f(x)=1$)

Comment: I think that the _real_ problem here isn't integration constant shenanigans, but rather what $I'$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Arthur Agreed. I think my answer now reflects that (in the sense that point 1 explains how the codomain of $I$ must actually be something other than $\mathbb R$, and point 2 explains how the domain of $I$ must be something other than $\mathbb R$, and the concluding that $I'$ is not well defined in that case)

Comment: $\int f(x) \, dx$ is neither a function nor a familiy of functions; it's just a value, and $f \mapsto \int f(x) \, dx$ is a functional (domain: a set of functions).

Comment: @md2perpe if $f\mapsto \int f(x)dx$ is a functional that maps to a set of functions, then clearly, $\int f(x)dx$ is a set of functions, is it not?

Comment: @5xum. It does not map to a set of functions; it's *domain*, not *range*, is a set of functions. The range is a set of scalars (e.g. $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). This means that it takes a function and returns a scalar value.

Comment: @md2perpe Really? So which scalar value is $\int x dx$ equal to?

Comment: @md2perpe Keep in mind I am not asking what is $\int_a^b x dx$ equal to.

Comment: @5xum. Oh, I'm sorry, then it's true that the range is a set of functions. The domain is still also a set of functions. Then we have $I(f)'(x) = f(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @md2perpe I agree. Which is why I wrote that OP should actually write $(I(f))(x)$ instead of $I(f(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem: evaluation $\ne$ composition. In symbols:
$$I(f)\ne I\circ f.$$
Consequence: you can't use the chain rule.

Comment: I fail to understand this. I know what a composite function is and also in the wikipedia page it says that this would be true. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MattiP., another example: the evaluation at $a$ defined by $e_a(f) = f(a)$. $e_a\circ f$ does not makes sense.

Comment: @MattiP., and ($(g\circ f )(x) = g(f(x))$) $\ne$ ($(g\circ f ) = g(f)$).